Allocating a variable's type based on another variable's type in a subroutine
Let's say I have a variable foo which is of class(BaseType). Type1 and Type2 are types that extends BaseType, and I am trying to allocate foo to be the same type as a second variable, bar, which has previously been declared as either Type1 or Type2.
When I try to write a subroutine using the function TYPE to do this, I get a compilation error:
SUBROUTINE TESTING(foo,bar)
CLASS(BaseType), INTENT(INOUT) :: foo 
CLASS(BaseType), INTENT(IN) :: bar
ALLOCATE(TYPE(bar)::foo)
END SUBROUTINE TESTING

The compilation error is:
Error: Allocate-object at (1) is neither a data pointer nor an allocatable variable

Is there a way to do what I am describing? Or is there an error with my implementation? This subroutine is written in a module if that is relevant. Thanks in advance.

Use tag [tag:fortran] for all  Fortran questions and read and follow the instructions displayed when adding a tag. Tags are very important here. There was no polymorphism in the very old Fortran 90.

The specifier mold= is exactly for this but you also have to fix what the error message is complaining about. foo is neither allocatable nor pointer and it must be one of these to appear in allocate. After fixing that, you can do
allocate(bar, mold=foo)


mold= is almost certainly what you want once you have the allocatable attribute, but I'd just check source= as well, and also simple assignment

As stated in another answer,
mold= can be used in the allocate statement to "copy" the dynamic type and type parameters, to an allocatable or pointer object.  Further, as commented on that answer source= or an assignment statement can be used to do this and also copy the value.
To add to that answer, though, we can address the confusion in the attempt of the question.
TYPE(bar) is not a standard function reference which returns the type of its argument bar. There is no function in Fortran which does this.1 Much as one can't reflectively use the name of a variable, the type of an entity is not itself an entity. Use of a type in an allocate statement, an array constructor, or a type guard always requires an explicit type name and not an evaluated expression.1

1 Before anyone gets excited about how TYPEOF(bar) exists starting in Fortran 2023, I'll note that this isn't the same thing. TYPEOF isn't a function and is more like TYPE, and in any event, TYPEOF works with the declared type of an entity not its dynamic type.
